# How can I pull user info for posts from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, a "users" and "updates" table. I want to grab these values from the tables:

id, username - from the "users" table
message, createdOn - from the "updates" table

I need to grab these values for a specified user and friends of the user. I have already created an array containing all friends id's that would look like this:

```
array(1,3,7,21,45);
```

I need a query that will select all of the updates with an matching the previous array. The "updates" table also has a column "uid" which defines the user who posted the update. This is what I have so far:

```
$updates = "SELECT users.id, users.username, updates.message, updates.createdOn FROM users, updates WHERE updates.uid = '". $_COOKIE['id'] ."' ". $friendsNews ." ORDER BY updates.createdOn DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
$updates = mysql_query( $updates );
```

This isn't working for me though, I created a foreach loop that also creates an or statement which is inserted into the query "$friendsNews" that looks like this:

```
foreach( $myFriends as $fid ) {
     $friendsNews .= " OR updates.uid = '". $fid ."'";
}
```

Once the entire query compiles the result of the query is this:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, updates.message, updates.createdOn FROM users, updates WHERE updates.uid = '1' OR updates.uid = '2' OR updates.uid = '3' ORDER BY updates.createdOn DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

If someone could help I would really appreciate it, I'm not very experienced with SQL join statements. Thanks!

Comment: What does $_COOKIE['id'] hold? the user id?

Comment: @Nouphal.M It simply holds the logged in users id, an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT users.id, users.username, updates.message, updates.createdOn, ". 
" updates.message, updates.createdOn ".
" FROM users ".
" INNER JOIN updates ON updates.uid = users.id ".
" WHERE  ".
" updates.uid  IN ( ".implode(', ', $myFriends)." )";
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to add "on" to:

`" INNER JOIN updates ON updates.uid = users.id ".`

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to grab all updates for the users specified in the ids array, the simplest way would be to use a sql `JOIN` and an `IN` clause

```
select users.id, users.username, u1.message, u1.createdOn
from updates as u1
join users as u2 on u2.id = u1.uid
where u1.uid in(1,3,7,21,45)
order by u1.createdOn desc limit 0, 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (in_array($_COOKIE['id'], $myFriends)) {
   $flist = implode(',', $myFriends) 
}else{
   $flist =  $_COOKIE['id'].','.implode(',', $myFriends);   //if $_COOKIE['id'] is differed.....
}

$sql = "SELECT users.id, users.username, updates.message, updates.createdOn,          
          updates.message, updates.createdOn FROM users INNER JOIN updates
              updates.uid = users.id WHERE updates.uid  IN ( ".$flist." )";
```

Help for Logged user is differed.....